# Android Application SQlite Access

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

Accessing the SQlite DB from activity works fine
eg.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     DatabaseHelper db;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        // Creating tags
        Tag tag1 = new Tag("Shopping");
        Tag tag2 = new Tag("Important");
        Tag tag3 = new Tag("Watchlist");
        Tag tag4 = new Tag("Androidhive");

        // Inserting tags in db
        long tag1_id = db.createTag(tag1);
        long tag2_id = db.createTag(tag2);
        long tag3_id = db.createTag(tag3);
        long tag4_id = db.createTag(tag4);

        Log.d("Tag Count", "Tag Count: " + db.getAllTags().size());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new        PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

but as soon as I take the DB code in Activity and call this in Application Constructor, I get null pointer.
eg

```
public class MainClass extends Application {
// Database Helper
private DatabaseHelper db;
private static final String LOG = MainClass.class.getName();

public MainClass()  {
    Log.d(LOG, "MainClass Init");
    db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: When are you calling the `Application` constructor?

Comment: Application constructor is called by manifest file. like I am specifying mf file as                                                <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="MainClass">

Answer (score 3):

Application classes don't need an explicit constructor.

At object instantiation phase when the constructor is called, the `Application` is not set up as a `Context` yet. `getApplicationContext()` won't work.

You can use the `Application` as a `Context` only in `onCreate()` or later.

Comment: How to create database at application startup time ?

Comment: thanks laalto. creating db in app oncreate works. thanks mate